Ubuntu 23.10 Bluetooth connection to MX Master 3 issue
Fresh install of ubuntu 23.10, everything is up to date.
I go into GUI bluetooth manager and when I put my mouse into pairing mode, it appears correctly, however when I click on it to pair, it disappears and reappears unconnected ad-nauseam.
I opened terminal to see what was going on in the GUI
[DEL] Device D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92 MX Master 3
[NEW] Device D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92 MX Master 3
[CHG] Device 75:93:0F:D8:0D:D5 ManufacturerData Key: 0x004c (76)
[CHG] Device 75:93:0F:D8:0D:D5 ManufacturerData Value:
  10 06 37 1e 69 22 78 1a                          ..7.i"x.        
[DEL] Device 70:B4:30:CC:11:15 70-B4-30-CC-11-15
[DEL] Device EE:98:E2:D3:E5:B4 EE-98-E2-D3-E5-B4
[CHG] Device EE:9B:CA:A3:08:D3 RSSI: 0xffffffb6 (-74)
[CHG] Controller F4:4E:FC:98:CC:7D Discoverable: no
[CHG] Device D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92 TxPower is nil
[CHG] Device D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device EE:9B:CA:A3:08:D3 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device D0:A5:B9:5A:8A:6C RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 75:93:0F:D8:0D:D5 TxPower is nil
[CHG] Device 75:93:0F:D8:0D:D5 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 7D:30:62:A6:82:D9 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 77:3C:7C:EC:5C:1E RSSI is nil
[CHG] Controller F4:4E:FC:98:CC:7D Discovering: no
[DEL] Device D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92 MX Master 3
[CHG] Controller F4:4E:FC:98:CC:7D Discoverable: yes
[CHG] Controller F4:4E:FC:98:CC:7D Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92 MX Master 3
[CHG] Device 77:3C:7C:EC:5C:1E RSSI: 0xffffffb5 (-75)
[CHG] Device EE:9B:CA:A3:08:D3 RSSI: 0xffffffbf (-65)
[CHG] Device 7D:30:62:A6:82:D9 RSSI: 0xffffffaa (-86)
[CHG] Device D0:A5:B9:5A:8A:6C RSSI: 0xffffffb9 (-71)
[CHG] Device 75:93:0F:D8:0D:D5 RSSI: 0xffffffad (-83)
[CHG] Device 75:93:0F:D8:0D:D5 TxPower: 0x000c (12)
[CHG] Device EE:9B:CA:A3:08:D3 RSSI: 0xffffffb7 (-73)
[CHG] Device 75:93:0F:D8:0D:D5 TxPower is nil
[CHG] Device 75:93:0F:D8:0D:D5 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device D0:A5:B9:5A:8A:6C RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 7D:30:62:A6:82:D9 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device EE:9B:CA:A3:08:D3 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 77:3C:7C:EC:5C:1E RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92 TxPower is nil
[CHG] Device D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Controller F4:4E:FC:98:CC:7D Discovering: no
[CHG] Controller F4:4E:FC:98:CC:7D Discoverable: no
[DEL] Device D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92 MX Master 3
[CHG] Controller F4:4E:FC:98:CC:7D Discoverable: yes
[CHG] Controller F4:4E:FC:98:CC:7D Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92 MX Master 3

This is a snapshot of me attempting to connect to the mouse twice.
I attempted to force the connection in bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# trust D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92
[CHG] Device D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92 Trusted: yes
Changing D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# pair D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92
Attempting to pair with D7:BF:DA:F6:F5:92
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed

I've tried this on each of the mouse's three channels and all have the same issue. I'm going to order a logitech brand unifying receiver and see if that changes anything.
This mouse works great on my chromebook and my windows PC.
